# Product of Positive stable matrix and positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume A is positive stable matrix (a matrix is called positive stable if every eigenvalue has positive real part). Is there any positive definite matrix P (desirably diagonal matrix) such that $PA$ is positive definite?

Note: A real matrix $B$ is positive definite iff the symmetric part $\frac 12(B+B^{T})$, is positive definite

Comment: In "G. Duan and R.J. Pattona Note on Hurwitz Stability of Matrices" mentioned that if the matrix A is Hurwitz stable, then there exists a symmetric positive definite matrix P such that the matrix AP is generalized negative definite.

Comment: As you use "positive definite" in the title and in the body of the Question, does it imply real and symmetric?  If not, how do you define "positive definite" without recourse to being real and symmetric?

Comment: Not necessarily symmetric. A real matrix A is positive definite iff the symmetric part  $1/2(A+A^{T})$, is positive definite.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there need to be some clarification on differences between positive definite and positive stable matrices.

$A$ is positive stable, if all of its eigen values have got positive real part. $A$ can be a non-hermition matrix.

$B$ is positive definite matrix, iff following conditions hold,
\begin{align}
B &= B^* \tag{1} \\
x^*Bx &> 0 \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{C}^n \tag{2}
\end{align}
where $\mathbb{C}^n$ is set of all nonzero complex vectors. Since $B$ is an hermition matrix, all its eigen values are real. Hence $(2)$ implies that all eigen values of matrix $B$ are positive.

From the above two definitions, it's clear that **ALL positive definite matrices are positive stable**, but converse is not true.

Now answering your question, if $P$ and $A$ are positive definite s.t. $PA$ is an hermition matrix, then $PA$ is positive definite. The proof follows from 1.0.3.1 in [1]. I can summarise the proof for you,
\begin{align}
x^*PAx &= x^* P^{1/2} (P^{-1/2}A P^{1/2})  P^{1/2} x \\
       &= (P^{1/2} x)^* (P^{-1/2}A P^{1/2}) (P^{1/2} x) \text{  \{Since $P=P^* \Rightarrow P^{1/2} = (P^{1/2})^*$\}}  \\
       &= y^*Cy \hspace{3.95cm} \{C = P^{-1/2}A P^{1/2}, y = P^{1/2} x \} \\
       & > 0 \hspace{4.5cm} \text{  \{Since $C$ is similar to $A$, and $A$ is positive definite\}}
\end{align}

Actually more is true. The above proof holds for all matrix $A$ s.t. $A+A^*$ is positive definite!

Reference:

[1] "Topics in Matrix Algebra" by Roger A. Horn and Charles R. Johnson